# MiniBatchKMeans Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-computing

I am using the function MiniBatchKMeans() from scikitlearn. Well, 
in its documentation there are:

> **batch_size** : int, optional, default: 100
>   Size of the mini batches.
>
> **init_size** : int, optional, default: 3 * batch_size
>   Number of samples to randomly sample for speeding up the initialization (sometimes at the expense of accuracy): the only algorithm is initialized by running a batch KMeans on a random subset of the data. This needs to be larger than n_clusters.

I didn't understand it very well, because it seems that the final dimension of the mini batch is **3*batch_size** and not the one specified by **batch_size** argument.

Am I misunderstanding something. If so, some one can explain those two arguments. It I am right, why there are these two arguments since they seems to be redundant.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The batch size is defined by `batch_size`, period. Furthermore you can define `init_size` which is the size of samples taken to **initiallize** the process, and **by default** it is 3*`batch_size`. You can simply set `bath_size=100` and `init_size=10` and then 10 samples are used to perform initialization (kmeans is not globaly convergent, there are many techniques to deal with it onthe initialization stage) and later on batch of 100 will be used during the algorithm execution.

Comment: Do you mean with initialization the process to choose the initial centroids?

Comment: Yes. By default the k-means++ heuristic is used during this step.